# $|A|$,$|B|$, and $|C|$ in a $k$-regular tripartite graph $(A, B, C)$

Tags: graph-theory

Let $k>0$ and let $G$ be a $k$-regular tripartite graph with partition $(A, B, C)$.

I want to prove that it is not necessary that $|A|=|B|=|C|$.

As a counterexample, I constructed the graph shown in picture below, with $k=1$, $|A|=1$, $|B|=3$, and $|C|=2$.

[image]

Is that it? I mean, I see that it **is**, but I tend to be extremely suspicious when the answer is too easy.

Comment: Yes, it is.  I'm filling the character limit with this sentence.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer and the time it took you to write it :)

Comment: You can actually find a counterexample for every given $k$ too and for $t$-partite graphs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct, though your is $3K_{2}$ (the union of $3$ disjoint $K_{2}$'s). Technically, your graph is tripartite. More precisely, it is bipartite.

A k-partite graph is defined as a graph that can be colored using $k$ colors, such that no two adjacent vertices have the same color. A $c$-colorable graph is $k$-colorable for all $k > c$. So your graph is tripartite.

Comment: So, it's that simple, nice. Thanks!